# api version value by default in swagger-ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I have configure swagger in our [asp.core wep-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) project and its working perfectly fine.Now i am looking into solution when [swagger-ui](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) appears as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFVxw.jpg

the api version part should be fill automatically as per configuration from code side.

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "My API",
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = "My Api",
                    Url = "https://109.com/"
                }
            });
            var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                {"Bearer", new string[] { }},
            };
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(security);
        });
```

Comment: So what is your question? What do you have problems with, where are you stuck?

Comment: i need to autofill versio part inside swager-ui inspite of i am adding that api version all the time whenever i am trying some api considering my api version is 1 that is fixed @nvoigt

Comment: @nvoigt i am using **Global route prefix** that is from [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/) as now my prefix template is `opt.UseCentralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute("api/v{version:apiVersion}"));` so now for that template variable i need to pass value from configuration

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer` packages to enable the API versioning in Swagger.

You can check the additional details at [here](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation).

In `ConfigureServices` method define the versioning scheme as

```
 services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o =>
 {
      o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
      o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
 });
 services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
 {
     config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
     config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
     config.ReportApiVersions = true;
 });
```

Comment: i am using **Global route prefix**  that is from [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/) as now my prefix template is `opt.UseCentralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute("api/v{version:apiVersion}"));` so now for that template variable i need to pass value from configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl=true` to tell swagger to replace the version in the controller route and configure the api version:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options => options.ReportApiVersions = true);
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddVersionedApiExplorer(
          options =>
          {
              ////The format of the version added to the route URL  
              options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
              //Tells swagger to replace the version in the controller route  
              options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
          });
```

Also you need to add this to your controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
```